# How to perform a new query on every row that starts with a number

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I need to perform a query on every row that starts with a number, 
I don't want to get all the rows in a single a query, I want to loop and query every row starts with a number , here is how am trying to call it.

```
    number =0
    while number < 10 :
        cursorObj.execute("SELECT * FROM BADGE_UNIQUEID WHERE BADGEID LIKE '?%' " , number)
        try:
            print(cursorObj.fetchall()[0])
        except:
            print("it was none")
        number += 1
```

it gives me this error :

`('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')`

Comment: Better why just use a procedure? ...and later put all parameters

Comment: @Giovanni Am really a beginner in SQL querying, can you please give me more details?

Comment: Try this: `strLikeCond = str(number)+'%'
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM BADGE_UNIQUEID WHERE BADGEID like '%s'" % strLikeCond)`

Comment: Are you asking how to check in SQL Server if a the values stored in a column begin with a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like this

```
 while number < 10 :


    query = 'SELECT * FROM BADGE_UNIQUEID WHERE BADGEID LIKEe '+ "'"+ str(number)+"%'"

    try:
        cur.execute(query)
        print(cur.fetchall()[0])

    except:
        print("it was none")
    number += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you better use a procedure when you make queries from python (like client) , for example:

```
--Python

sqlExecSP="""\
        EXEC [dbo].[NameProcedure] @p1 = ?;
        """                     
params = (p1)
cursor.execute(sqlExecSP, params)

--SQL

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.NameProcedure @p1 varchar(30)
AS
SELECT Top 1 Colum1,Column2 
FROM MyTable
WHERE Colum1 Like '' + @p1 + '%';
GO
```